# Interactive physics simulations and animations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, applied-physics

What are some free and open-source interactive simulations, illustrations, animations, demonstrations, videos, calculators and other resources for experimental physics and mathematics like the [Wolfram demonstration project](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?limit=20&topic=Physics)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the question is really quite large, but for what it's worth:

1. My go-to site for simulations is the [PhET Interactive Simulations Project](https://phet.colorado.edu/) at the University of Colorado Boulder. They have some very nice stuff.
2. I also like [falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/mathphysics.html), they have some excellent simulations. I particularly like their [2D Electrostatics Applet](https://www.falstad.com/emstatic/index.html) which I've found to be really useful in lab courses.
3. Andrew Duffy from Boston University has some simple (mainly mechanics-related) simulations [here](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eduffy/). They also have a nice list of possible laboratory demonstrations [here](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eduffy/).
4. [Merlot II](http://www.merlot.org/merlot/materials.htm?category=2736) is pretty amazing too, it's like a search engine for educational material. You can choose to search for "animations", "simulations", or "tutorials".
5. [The Physics Front](https://www.compadre.org/precollege/search/search.cfm?gs=224&SS=266&b=1) (from the American Association of Physics Teachers) is another great collection that links to other online resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are many youtube channels that animate very good animation videos. Some of them are here:

- [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw): 3Blue1Brown is a math YouTube channel created by Grant Sanderson. The channel focuses on higher mathematics with a distinct visual perspective. Topics covered include linear algebra, calculus, neural networks, the Riemann hypothesis, Fourier transform, quaternions, and topology.
- [MinutePhysics](https://www.youtube.com/user/minutephysics) :
- [ThinkTwice](https://www.youtube.com/c/ThinkTwiceLtu)
- [Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/c/Mathologer)
- [PBS Space Time](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g)

There is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcgJro0sTiM) video where grant talks about some other animation creators.

---

Now It's best if you animate things by yourself Because it's hard for someone to know what's hard for you to visualize. You can learn [p5.js](https://p5js.org/).p5.js is a JavaScript library for creative coding, with a focus on making coding accessible and inclusive for artists, designers, educators, beginners, and anyone else! p5.js is free and open-source because we believe software, and the tools to learn it, should be accessible to everyone.

There is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vX8wT1G798&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aFlwukCmDf0-1-uSR7mklK) series by Daniel Shiffman who run a channel [The coding train](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman). There [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70MQ-FugwbI&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZV4yEcW3uDwOgGXKUUsPOM) second season for the same series. You can go through his [book](https://g.co/kgs/fjKQAM) too if you want.

There is another coding program name [processing](https://processing.org/) 3 to animate things based on java language.

---

The following site has good animation if you can find what you are looking for.

- [Processing 3](https://processing.org/examples/)
- [Open Processing](https://www.openprocessing.org/)
- [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)